# how get values from object to local variable c#

Tags: c#, winforms

i have following code please help me how to get values from object

```
 APIKarho objapi = new APIKarho();
           object obje = objapi.GetBookingFromAPI();

           string ss = obje.booking_id;
```

[image]

Comment: you should cast the object to the class it originally is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast the object to the `class` it originally is (what class is the `object` returned by `GetBookingFromAPI()`) before you could access its `field/property/method`. Example:

```
public MyClass { // suppose this is the original class of the object returned by GetBookingFromAPI
    public int booking_id; 
}

APIKarho objapi = new APIKarho();
object obje = objapi.GetBookingFromAPI();
string ss = ((MyClass)obje).booking_id; //note the casting to MyClass here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what type GetBookingFromAPI() returns, and change the type of obje. Just move your mouse over GetBookingFromAPI().

```
GetBookingFromAPIType obje = objapi.GetBookingFromAPI();

string ss = obje.booking_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your api returns an object of an unknown type or a type that you cannot cast to you could use the `dynamic` keyword.

```
dynamic obj = api.GetBookingFromAPI();
string ss = obj.booking_id;
```

Note that this works only if booking_id is actually a string.